# Row deduplication problem with daily updated rows. How to avoid counting the same row?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

This particular dataframe is updated daily with the "Customer ID" ,"status" and the "date" that said update occured, here is an example:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SLTR.png)

Some clients receive updates daily, other don't. Some can have a status changed in a matter of days from 'no' to 'yes' and vice versa

Status with yes can be fetched with :

```py
df = df \
    .select('id','status','date') \
    .filter(
        (col('date') >= '2022-10-01') &
        (col('date') <= '2022-10-31') & 
        (col(status) == "yes"))
```

The second selection must have none of the ID's present in the "yes" query. See ID "123" per example, if i exclued all rows with "yes" i am still counting that client in my "no" part of the query.

Tried using an OVER function to create a flag based on the ID to exclude what i already selected then apply a filter but it does not work, pyspark says  that the expression is not supported within a window function.

```py
partition = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")

df = df \
    .withColumn("results", 
     when((col("status") == "approved").over(partition), '0')
    .otherwise("1"))
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o808.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expression '(result_decisaofinal#8593 = APROVA)' not supported within a window function.;;
```

Comment: so for your example, in the query to retrieve the "no" rows you only want to get 4141? since both 5555 and 123 also had a row with yes?

Comment: Exactly, only one row for each ID following the rule:
if Id has one row containing "yes" most recent "yes"else most recent "no"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your comment:

> Exactly, only one row for each ID following the rule: if Id has one row containing "yes" most recent "yes" else most recent "no"

You can do it with a simple row_number window function, partitioning by customer and ordering by the status (with 'yes' being before 'no' when using `desc` and date)

```py
from datetime import date
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
data = [
    {'customer': 123, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 25)},
    {'customer': 123, 'status': 'yes', 'date': date(2022, 10, 22)},
    {'customer': 4141, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 25)},
    {'customer': 4141, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 22)},
    {'customer': 4141, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 15)},
    {'customer': 5555, 'status': 'yes', 'date': date(2022, 10, 25)},
    {'customer': 5555, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 22)},
    {'customer': 5555, 'status': 'no', 'date': date(2022, 10, 15)},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

part = Window.partitionBy('customer').orderBy(F.col('status').desc(), F.col('date').desc())
df2 = df.withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(part)).filter('rn=1').drop('rn')
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+--------+----------+------+
|customer|date      |status|
+--------+----------+------+
|123     |2022-10-22|yes   |
|4141    |2022-10-25|no    |
|5555    |2022-10-25|yes   |
+--------+----------+------+
```

Comment: Very simple and efficient, it was what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution which may work but i am not sure if its good solution in terms of time and resources so if anyone knows how to improve it please leave a comment. For this moment i wasnt able to figure out anything else but maybe it will be usefull for you. I have a feeling that there is some trick that i dont know to do it smarter :D

```
import datetime 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x = [(123,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,25)),
    (123,"yes", datetime.date(2020,10,22)),
    (4141,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,25)),
    (4141,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,22)),
    (4141,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,15)),
    (5555,"yes", datetime.date(2020,10,25)),
    (5555,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,22)),
    (5555,"no", datetime.date(2020,10,15))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=['customer_id', 'status', 'date'])
groupedDf = df.groupBy(F.col('customer_id'), F.col('status')).agg(F.max("date").alias("most_recent_date")).cache()
trueDf = groupedDf.filter(F.col('status') == F.lit('yes'))
falseDf = groupedDf.filter(F.col('status') == F.lit('no'))
falseWithNoCorrecpondingTrueDf = falseDf.join(trueDf, falseDf.customer_id == trueDf.customer_id, "anti")
finalDf = falseWithNoCorrecpondingTrueDf.union(trueDf)
```

No need for separate variables for dfs, i added it to make it more descriptive

Description step by step:

- First i am grouping records to get max date for customer_id and
  status
- Then i cache result of grouping as i know that it will be used two
  times and i dont want to compute it two times
- I am splitting result of group by into two parts, one with "yes",
  other with "no"
- I am dropping "no" which have correspoding "yes" because according to
  your logic they are not going to be used
- I am doing a union of "no" which left with all "yes" which should
  give me resulting df you want to have

Output from sample job:

```
+-----------+------+----------------+
|customer_id|status|most_recent_date|
+-----------+------+----------------+
|       4141|    no|      2020-10-25|
|        123|   yes|      2020-10-22|
|       5555|   yes|      2020-10-25|
+-----------+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Very cleaver sir, seems to work fine too., Thanks